# Is it Possible to show and hide some Slickgrid Columns on button click

Tags: jquery-plugins, slickgrid, dynamic-columns

I need to show/hide some of the slickgrid columns on the click of a button. Is it possible?

For example , I have a slickgrid having 3 columns. On click of a button I want to show three more columns i.e 4,5,6. On clicking the button again these columns should hide and another div should take its place. So basically toggle 3 of the 6 slickgrid columns. 
Thanks

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373336/possible-to-hide-a-slickgrid-column-without-removing-it-from-the-columns-array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SlickGrid doesn't have a concept of showing or hiding columns.  It shows whatever columns you specify in the constructor or in a later call to `grid.setColumns()`.  If you want to hide a column, just remove it from the columns array you call `grid.setColumns()` again.

You can keep the original columns array with all the columns in a separate variable.

Comment: thanks a lot!..i guess using that along with dynamically changing the grid width helped!!